# Manual Azure Backup Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

Tried to export data in CosmosDB but it was not successful. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/storage-explorer, by using this tool I can export the data inside the cosmosdb, but no option to export. Tried to do the instructions here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/documentdb-data-migration-tool/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#JSON, but error is being encountered.

Can you help me how to do this in **Data Factory** or **any steps just to manual backup cosmos DB**?

i tried doing the backup through azure data factory but data factory can't seem to connect to cosmos db, it's so weird 'cause the primary string/secondary string that I used is in the details of the cosmos db

Thank you.

Comment: What error do you encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one worked for me... since my SSL in my Macbook did not work, I did these steps from the Azure VM that I created.

Steps:
Download MongoDB Community Server Client tool as per your OS version and MongoDB compatible version.
(Or you can download [v3.2.22 for Windows X64] directly at here, please don’t download the version beyond 4.2 as it’s incompatible)

After installing the MongoDB client tools, go to the installation directory -> go to the subfolder “bin” containing the mongoexport.exe, then issue below command to export your data:
mongoexport --host=: -u= -p= --db=  --collection= --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --out=

Note 1: You can find the , ,  and  in Cosmos DB Portal – “Connection String”

Answer (score 1):

> Can you help me how to do this in Data Factory

According to your description,it seems you have trouble with export data,not import data. You could use [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in ADF which supports [cosmos db connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db).For you needs,cosmos db is source dataset and please add one more sink dataset(destination). Such as some json files in the blob storage.Just make sure you configure right authentication information with your cosmos db account.

ADF is more suitable for the batch back up or daily back up.

> or any steps just to manual backup cosmos DB

Yes,Storage Explorer is not for exporting data from cosmos db,Data migration tool is the suitable option.Please install the tool and refer to some details from this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#export-to-json-file

DMT is more suitable for single back up.Surely,it also supports execution in the batch if you use command line to execute it.

Comment: yes export data
thank you so much for your answer
i'll try it

Comment: @user12817379 Hi,any updates here?Does my answer helps you?

Comment: already tried this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#export-to-json-file) but I think I am not doing this right. How to make a blob?

with regard to copy activity, i am confuse on how to do it.. sorry, i'm only new to azure so I am so confuse/overwhelm in it

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB Data Migration tool can be used to export data from Cosmos DB.

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#export-to-json-file

Comment: thank yo so much.. i'll take a look into it
i tried doing the backup through azure data factory but data factory can't seem to connect to cosmos db, it's so weird 'cause the primary string/secondary string that I used is in the details of the cosmos db